# Change response with angular-cli proxy

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I would like to change the server response in the proxy configuration of angular-cli.

I tried to listen for response events or somehow access the payload but had not luck yet.

Would like todo something like that:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            if (req.url === '/api/user') {
                res.event('data', function (payload) {
                   payload.userName = 'local';
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I expect to change the response with middleware function or something like that. Also all event callbacks on res are not called, would like to know why?